# It's not working using 'a' to submit the form in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to submit the request with post method by clicking the element `a` in HTML. But it always refreshes current page, even the `action` is updated with correct value.

This is how I submit the request.

```
$(function() {
    $('.detail a').click(function() {
        $('#cityId').val($(this).data('cid'));
        $('#cityName').val($(this).data('cn'));
        $('#parentIds').val($(this).data('pids'));

        $('#cityForm').submit();
    });
});
```

I passed the values to the hidden elements for submitting with `POST` method. Before the `submit()`, I checked and the action attribute of form is the right URL I want. But, after it, it didn't redirect to the URL I set, it just refreshed the current page.

This is the `a` in my code:

```
<a href data-cid="<c:out value='${cc.id}'/>" data-pids="<c:out value='${cc.type}'/>"
```

This is how the `form` looks like:

```
<form id="cityForm" method="post" action="<%=basePath%><c:out value='${sp}'/>">
```

It did work in IE. I searched online and found some solutions saying that it's caused by Chrome takes it as the same request, so I need to add a timestamp after the URL, but didn't work for me.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Position of script and set href="" may be issue.

Comment: @GrvTyagi What do you mean? I need to set href="" ?

Comment: @Sky means its due to set it as null string, use href = '#'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a link with empty `href` attribute, it will become current page URL, so when you click such link, page just refreshes. If you want to bind some action to `a` element, you have to prevent its default behavior, using `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.detail a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#cityId').val($(this).data('cid'));
        $('#cityName').val($(this).data('cn'));
        $('#parentIds').val($(this).data('pids'));

        $('#cityForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Nature of `a` tag is to navigate user, as we want to invoke the function n click of this element, we need to prevent default nature of `a` tag..

Comment: I got it. Thanks, then if I set href to '#', it can work too, right?

Comment: @Sky If you set `href` to `#`, you will as well need to use `event.preventDefault()` because `#` link scrolls page to the top. IMHO the best solution is to use `button` instead of `a`, as Gerald wrote. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: @RayonDabre Yes, but I assume OP doesn't want any side effects.

Comment: Yes, Rayon is right. It can work, but with a bit suspending.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `<input type="submit">` or a `<button type="submit">` instead of a link. You can use CSS to style the `input` exactly like an `a` tag and it will still work when JavaScript is disabled on the browser, which is not possible with your current solution.

```css
button[type=submit].link {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button[type=submit].link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="link">This is a submit button</button>
```

You should always build websites to be completely functional without JavaScript, then you can add JS to improve the comfort of navigating the site.

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
<a href="" data-cid="<c:out value='${cc.id}'/>" data-pids="<c:out value='${cc.type}'/>" >Submit Form</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work. Just a little suspending when clicking the element.

Comment: `a` element without `href` attribute look just like `span`, see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9gg2zjh/).